# Fill iPhone Screen With Translucent Mask EXCEPT For One Area

Tags: iphone, uiview

I already have a view box showing the user where to center the text they would like to analyze, but I would like to fill the rest of the screen with a translucent gray mask. Unfortunately I can't simply pre-render what I want (as shown in the image) in Photoshop and just add it to the project because I need the view box to remain programmatically added separately. Is there a way to add color to a view in all areas except a designated area?

[image: Mock Image of iPhone Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add 4 translucent views (fill them with black and set their alpha property to 0.5 for example) on top of the view? One on top, bottom, left and right of the area you want translucent?

That shouldn't be too hard to do, you can just modify the size of the views based on where you want the box to be.

Comment: Yea I thought of doing that, but was afraid there would be issues due to the rounded edges on the view box. The image shown has more exaggerated rounding than my actual app, but i imagine it to present a problem. I am in the process of trying that now anyway.

Comment: I got the display to look like I wanted using Chris Grant's method, but this was only possible because the rounded corners of my view box in my actual app have a much smaller radius. This method would not work using a view box with larger rounded corners in the image above.

Comment: So do you have rounded corners or not? How did you do this? I don't think it would be hard to add rounded corners. You can create them in code or by just creating a semi-transparent png file for each corner, and just calculate their positions like you did for the other rectangles.

Comment: The actual view box in my app has small rounded corners, pre-rendered when i created the box in Photoshop. They aren't nearly as noticeable as the example I provided, so getting the mask to cover all of the background was possible. I just had to overlap the two views a bit. The gray was covered by the red border on the left and right side.